# Difference between tabbar based application and tab bar view controller in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am new to iphone development.what is the difference between tabbar based application and creating a tab bar using tabbar controller in a view based application.Which has the major advantages?Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is what code is auto-generated for you. You could recreate either project from a "Window-based application" project by adding the appropriate components.

If you're new to iPhone development, you can bootstrap your learning process by having Xcode generate the most detailed project that applies, so you don't have to do so much bookkeeping to start.